# JCL Sort to get selective records

Tags: sorting, mainframe

I have one input file like below:

```
india
delhi
kolkata
chennai
orrisa
kerala
banglore
```

Now my requirement is my jcl search kolkata and write output file till orrisa. 
so my output would be:

```
kolkata
chennai
orrisa
```

Comment: What is the sort utility?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You mention JCL, so I assume mainframe. However, your output is not sorted (at least on the data presented), so I must assume that you were given this as an assignment and part of that is to use SORT. This is possible, however I direct you to the [relevant documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.icea100/toc.htm) and read on your options. I believe SORT is not the best utility for this exercise, however.

Comment: JCL cannot do this and tagging your problem with JCL is wrong. The sort solutuion is the same whether it is done in batch (JCL) or interactively. JCL is simply a means by which you let the operating system know what programs you wish to run and the resources required by those programs. JCL is 'discarded' once the information has been communicated to the OS. Theactions required will be carried out after the JCL has been 'discarded'.